# Let users enter Python code and run it on a Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, docker

I want to let users come to my website, type in python code, and then be able to run it. For this question, imagine jsfiddle, except for python.

Right now I am building my app in Rails on Heroku. How can I let a person enter python code into my form, and run it for them?

Requirements:
 1. You can't simply let a person run python commands on your server. For obvious reasons this isn't safe.
 2. This needs to support concurrency, so if many people are running their scripts, your system can scale.
 3. Encapsulation - you can't access other peoples data from your script.

Technologies that have containers like Docker seem to address these issues. Can it be used for this problem?

Comment: If you're going to downvote and vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why and I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge

Comment: You can always just shell out to system python. Although this opens a whole can of worms.

Comment: @guarav ruby bridge looks interesting, does it encapsulate the python well? So if somebody `requires os`, is my whole system going down?

Comment: @Sergio, shelling out to python will definitely open a can of worms, and that is why it's not an answer :)

Comment: Interesting question! but a bit too broad a topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation of Python written to run in the browser called [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/). You could also try [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/). This is a general answer, to a general question, but I'd suggest this might be a simpler place to start than running the python code on the server.